# How to disable training of some layers?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

How to disable training of some layers?

I was trying standard way like:

```
def get_model():
    weight_decay=0.0

    inputs = Input(shape=(INPUT_IMAGE_H, INPUT_IMAGE_W, 3))

    # Block 1
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv1', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(inputs)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv2', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool')(x)

    # Block 2
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv1', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv2', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block2_pool')(x)

    # Block 3
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv1', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv2', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv3', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block3_pool')(x)

    # Block 4
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv1', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv2', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv3', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block4_pool')(x)

    # Block 5
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv1', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv2', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv3', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block5_pool')(x)

    # Convolutional layers transfered from fully-connected layers
    x = Conv2D(4096, (7, 7), activation='relu', padding='same', name='fc1', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Conv2D(4096, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same', name='fc2', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

    # Classifying layer
    x = Conv2D(NUMBER_OF_CLASSES, (1, 1), kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='sigmoid', padding='valid', strides=(1, 1), kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)

    x = BilinearUpSampling2D(size=(32, 32))(x)

    model = Model(inputs, x)

    weights_path = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', '.keras/models/fcn_vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5'))
    model.load_weights(weights_path, by_name=True)

    #Freeze layers
    for layer in model.layers[-8]:
        layer.trainable = False

    model.compile(optimizer=Adadelta(), loss='binary_crossentropy')

    print('len(model.layers)', len(model.layers)) #
    print(model.summary()) #

    return model

model = get_model()
```

But get error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-849aac962bb2> in <module>()
     71     return model
     72 
---> 73 model = get_model()

<ipython-input-23-849aac962bb2> in get_model()
     61 
     62     #Freeze layers
---> 63     for layer in model.layers[-8]:
     64         layer.trainable = False
     65 

TypeError: 'Conv2D' object is not iterable
```

It also don't work like this:

```
def get_model():
    weight_decay=0.0

    #inputs = Input((None, None, 3)) # will not work with BilinearUpSampling2D
    #inputs = Input((INPUT_IMAGE_H, INPUT_IMAGE_W, 3))

    inputs = Input(shape=(INPUT_IMAGE_H, INPUT_IMAGE_W, 3))

    # Block 1
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv1', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(inputs)
    x.trainable = False
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv2', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x.trainable = False
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool')(x)

    # Block 2
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv1', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x.trainable = False
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv2', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x.trainable = False
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block2_pool')(x)

    # Block 3
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv1', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x.trainable = False
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv2', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x.trainable = False
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv3', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x.trainable = False
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block3_pool')(x)

    # Block 4
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv1', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x.trainable = False
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv2', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x.trainable = False
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv3', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x.trainable = False
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block4_pool')(x)

    # Block 5
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv1', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x.trainable = False
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv2', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x.trainable = False
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv3', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block5_pool')(x)

    # Convolutional layers transfered from fully-connected layers
    x = Conv2D(4096, (7, 7), activation='relu', padding='same', name='fc1', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Conv2D(4096, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same', name='fc2', kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

    # Classifying layer
    x = Conv2D(NUMBER_OF_CLASSES, (1, 1), kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='sigmoid', padding='valid', strides=(1, 1), kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)

    x = BilinearUpSampling2D(size=(32, 32))(x)

    model = Model(inputs, x)

    weights_path = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', '.keras/models/fcn_vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5'))
    model.load_weights(weights_path, by_name=True)

    model.compile(optimizer=Adadelta(), loss='binary_crossentropy')

    print('len(model.layers)', len(model.layers)) #
    print(model.summary()) #

    return model

model = get_model()
```

As I can see in model summary all weights are trainable:

```
Total params: 134,272,835
Trainable params: 134,272,835
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: `model.layers[-8]` acceses the element at position -8 and does not create a slice. You probably meant something like `model.layers[:-8]`

Comment: @FlyingTeller Oh, yes it was a silly mistake.